# How to make a div fill the width of the viewport instead of its parent?

Tags: html, css, layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>Test</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
   <style>
      .container{
         max-width: 480px;
         margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .container .carousel{
         background-color: lightsalmon;
         height: 400px;
         width: 100%;
         /* Make the carousel's width fill the viewport */
      }

      .container .content{
         margin: 10px 0px;
         background-color: steelblue;
         height: 200px;
         width: 100%;
      }
   </style>
</body>

</html>
```

I have this kind of problem.

I need to make the carousel fill the entire viewport horizontally.

I don't want to use `position: absolute` cuz it will lose the height info to other elements, so I need to add more css to the container and if I need to change the height of the carousel, I need to modify both places. And I don't want to detach it from container as well cuz it suppose to be inside of the container.

So is there better a way that I only need to add some css to `.carousel` to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title>Test</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
   <style>
       .container{
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .container .carousel{
     background-color: lightsalmon;
     height: 400px;
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: .5em;

     /* Make the carousel's width fill the viewport */
  }

  .container .content{
     margin: 10px 0px;
     background-color: steelblue;
     height: 200px;
     width: 100%;
    max-width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
  }
   </style>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for!
Also, you should not limit your container to certain width if you want your content elements to fill the complete view port, instead resize you elements as per the need.

Have created a new codepen sample. Check classes row, container-fluid and container [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePYEYG).

Comment: Well, the container's css was predefined in bootstrap, so the ```max-width``` is already restricted. I can hard code to change it but probably this isn't the best way.

Comment: Well then I'll suggest you to use `.container-fluid` class of bootstrap which will enable you to use entire width of your viewport. Below is the link from Bootstrap 4 documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <style>
    .container {
      max-width: 480px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .container .placeholder,
    .container .carousel {
      height: 400px;
    }
    
    .container .carousel {
      background-color: lightsalmon;
      width: 100vw;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .container .content {
      margin: 10px 0px;
      background-color: steelblue;
      height: 200px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Wait, I think I figured out a way to solve this.

By adding a placeholder div below the carousel sharing the same height.

Now I can make the carousel `position: absolute` without screwing up the contents below.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using viewport:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>viewport</title>
      <style>
        body {
          margin: 0 auto; 
          padding:0px;
        }
        .layer {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
          color:#000;
          text-align:center;
        }
        p {
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .one {
          background-color: blue;
        }
        .two {
          background-color: yellow;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <div class="layer one">
          <p>layer one</p>
        </div>
        <div class="layer two">
            <p>layer two</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```